# Setting TextMate 2 as Git's difftool

Tags: macos, git, textmate-2, difftool

Is it possible to set TextMate 2 as the default Git difftool/mergetool?

If so, what are the commands?

I have found instructions for the diffmerge tool [here](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/08/install-diffmerge-git-mac-os-x/), but I would like to try it with text mate, but I know that are the commands to use.

I am using Mac OS X 10.8 by the way.

Comment: Can textmate 2 be used as a diff/merge tool by default? I found that it has a [diff bundle](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles), is that what you plan on using?

Comment: I would like to use that bundle yes. But I am not sure that it can be used as such a tool.

Answer (score 1):

For a start;

```
git config --global diff.tool tmdiff
git config --global difftool.tmdiff.cmd 'git diff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"|mate'
```

which is run with `git difftool`

or

```
git diff | mate
```

Neither will get you the ability to merge the files, is that important to you?

```
git config --global core.editor "/usr/local/bin/mate -w"
```

Will set TextMate as the default editor, which I believe is how I'm resolving merge conflicts in TextMate.

As for the Diff bundle, it's just working for me.